# How can I restart JBoss 5.1 on AIX from a shell script?

Tags: jboss, shell

I need to **restart** JBoss from my script?

I tried to call

```
jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\shutdown.sh
```

and then

```
jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\run.sh
```

But unfortunately `shutdown.sh`  works asynchronously.

Is it possible to restart JBoss from shell script?

Comment: shutdown.bat on AIX, I don't believe you :)

Comment: BTW, I think this question belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I disagree, I think serverfault would point back here

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no built-in support for this in JBoss. But...

This message on the jboss-user mailing list might help you to build your own script: [Re: [jBoss-User] Starting jBoss as a service on Linux](http://www.mail-archive.com/jboss-user@list.working-dogs.com/msg10908.html)

**EDIT**: Just found another (very similar) post: [Running JBoss-5.1.0.GA as a service on Red Hat?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/455943/JBoss/Running-JBoss-GA-as-service) which could be a good source of inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I have a restart script, posted at https://serverfault.com/questions/56595/jboss-restart-script, written for red hat linux. I am sure it can be easily adapted to AIX.

One problem though - it still has problems with starting again, it seems that the jboss process hangs until the script is off. Running it again starts jboss immediately.